# Loop not outping desired result

Tags: c, sorting

I am trying to make a loop where I enter 30 or less student's GPA and get: the average gpa, highest and lowest gpa, adjusted average, see if a specific gpa was entered and display the contents of the array. But when I run the code I have, I can only enter one gpa...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GPA_COUNT 30

main(){
    int gpa [GPA_COUNT];
    int total = 0, i;
    double average;

    for(i = 0; i < GPA_COUNT; i++){
        printf("Enter student %i's GPA: \n", i + 1);
            scanf("%i", &gpa[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < GPA_COUNT; i++){
        total += gpa[i];


    if(gpa[i] > 2.0){
        printf("You need to study harder! \n");
    }
    else if(gpa[i] < 3.5){
        printf("Nice work! \n");
    }
}

    average = (double)total / GPA_COUNT;

    printf("The average GPA is: %.2lf \n", average);
    system("pause");
}
```

I would like to be able to enter the rest of the gpa's.

Comment: You don't ever want to use %i in scanf. use %d

Comment: GPA isn't an integer either I believe.....

Comment: The code actually asks for input all 30 times when I run it exactly as given.

Answer (score 0):

As Antii Haapala says in his comment, your problem is that you've initialized `gpa` as an integer, and are using `printf` to scan in an integer -- but are actually entering a double.

To fix it, you simply need to expect a double instead:

```
double gpa [GPA_COUNT];
// -- snip --
scanf("%lf", &gpa[i]);
```

I'm assuming you're a student, so here are a couple of other notes to help you improve your code:

- Take a look at your conditional when checking the student's GPA (what happens if a student scores a 1.0? A 4.0?)
- You can remove the `\n` from this line (`printf("Enter student %i's GPA: \n" i + 1);`) to have the inputs on the same line.
- Consider what will happen if someone throws garbage input at your program -- sanitizing user inputs is important! A safer, but still simple, method would be to read the user input as a string, and then attempt to convert the input with something like `strtod`.